# Specific case of "cannot return length of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror

So I'm making this program that loops through an array and returns each character in each element of the array. The elements in the array are lines of regular english. Here's my current code:

(I'm using javascript btw)

```
let array = ["this", "does", "not", "work"]
var current_pos_in_line = -1
var current_line = 0
var current_char
function advance() {
    current_pos_in_line += 1
    if (current_pos_in_line < array[current_line].length) {
        current_char = array[current_line][current_pos_in_line]
        return current_char
    } else {
        current_char = null
        newline()
    }
}
function newline() {
    current_line += 1
    current_pos_in_line = -1
    advance()
    

}

for (some_condition) {
    advance()
}
```

So you get the basic idea. The `advance` function loops through the current_line, and when it gets to the end, it increments `current_line` by 1. However, the problem is at the first `if...else` statement. There is an error returned when I try  to do `array[current_line]`. It's undefined!

I have no clue why this is the case, as `array[1]` is most definitely defined, and `current_line` is within the bounds of the length of `array`

Please help

Comment: it's not defined, or it wouldn't tell you otherwise.  You probably call `advance` too many times.

Comment: When you call `newline()` after the last character of the last word, `current_line` will point past the end of `array`.

Comment: @Barmar that might  be useful for me. Could you please elaborate and tell me how i could fix it?

Comment: What is the condition in `for (some_condition)`?

Comment: Check `if (current_line < array.length)`

Comment: @Barmar the condition in `for (some_condition)` isn't really important, it's just something that repeatedly calls advance until it cannot. Also, I will try checking `if (current_line < array.length)`

Comment: You have a potential infinite loop, with `advance` calling `newline` and `newline` calling `advance`. Eventually, it gets to the end of the array and causes an error

Comment: @Alanduan But it's apparently calling `advance()` too many times, so the condition is not correct. So it *is* important.

Comment: Hmm thanks for all this help, I will try see what the problem is and get back to you all later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change newline function as follows:

```
function newline() {
  if (current_line < array.length - 1) {
    current_line += 1
    current_pos_in_line = -1
    advance()
  }
}
```

That will prevent the error, though you should really check the some_condition that drives the advance function forward.

Comment: Thanks so much for that, that actually solved my problem. The issue was that advance() was just calling newline(), and there wasn't a stopping condition to that.